# Setter function with arguments

Tags: java, set, setter

Alright so I am doing an exercise where I have an object that contains scores for 3 tests.

I then have a set-function that takes 2 arguments, the test number and the score you set to it.

Right now my problem is that I do not know how to make the test number argument work correctly.

The code works if I do `test1 = score`, but when I put `student1.test1` in the set argument, for some reason it does not register.

I hope you can point me in the right direction, I would be really grateful!

I have a main class and a student class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.setTestScore(student1.test1, 50);
        System.out.print(student1.test1);
    }
}

public class Student {
    int test1;
    int test2 = 0;
    int test3;

    Student() { 
        int test1 = 0;
        int test2 = 0;
        int test3 = 0;    
    }

    public void setTestScore(int testNumber, int score){
        testNumber = score;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd be a lot better off making `test` a separate class.

Comment: I would suggest you make the ints in the student class private and in your constructor, you're re declaring your variables.

Comment: the base idea is wrong. you don't change value like that.

Comment: This won't work. Use a `Map`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider or an ArrayList, if the tests are indexed by integers anyways

Answer (score 3):

Java is a pass by value language, so when you pass `student1.test1` to `student1.setTestScore`, you are passing a copy of that member. You are not passing a reference to the member. Therefore the method can't change the member's value.

Even if the language allowed such modification, it would be a bad idea in terms of object oriented programming, since you normally make members private and don't access them directly from outside the class.

A possible alternative is to use an array :

```
public class Student {
    int[] test = new int[3];
    ...

    public void setTestScore(int testNumber, int score){
        if (testNumber >= 0 && testNumber < test.length)
            test[testNumber]=score;
    }
    ...
}
```

and you'd call the method like this :

```
student1.setTestScore(0, 50); // note that valid test numbers would be 0,1 and 2
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, I just added an example that illustrates this.

Comment: Does the pass by value claim matter in this case since the value being passed to the method is a primitive and not a reference to an object?

Comment: @bot Other languages, such as C and C++, allow passing a reference to any variable, so I'm assuming that's the cause of the OP's mistake

Comment: @Eran Fair enough. Although, if we restrict the scope of this question only to Java (as it has been tagged the same), then it would require a different kind of explanation for the OP.